# Need help understanding the range of Sbyte in x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I know that the range of a Sbyte is - 127 to 128. On an exam, they had Sbyte initialized as FC. How is this possible when FC exceeds the range of 128?

Comment: 0xFC = 0b11111100 which is -4  which is between -127 and 128

Comment: An Sbyte is -128 to +127.

Comment: Hex values are not generally considered signed, they generally are seen as a bit pattern.  that as old_timer points out is -4

Comment: How would I be able to convert this hexadecimal into - 4 decimal without turning it into binary first

Comment: @HaryLaroy Bits are bits. It's *how* they are read or interpreted that determines what they are. The same bit pattern can be used to represent arbitrary things. In this case, 0xFC is already -4, 252, or anything else that may be represented as such.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement